# Flowable Docker 6.4.2: NullPointerException when saving BPMN

Tags: flowable

Here are the steps to re-create the problem with a fresh deploy:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 flowable/all-in-one:6.4.2
```

And then make any dummy BPMN / save existing.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.initialize(DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.java:219) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.<init>(DefaultProcessDiagramCanvas.java:178) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.initProcessDiagramCanvas(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:1041) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateProcessDiagram(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:574) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:553) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generateImage(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:560) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.image.impl.DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.generatePngImage(DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator.java:565) ~[flowable-image-generator-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.util.ImageGenerator.createImage(ImageGenerator.java:39) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.service.ModelImageService.generateThumbnailImage(ModelImageService.java:70) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.service.ModelImageService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6d09a974.invoke(<generated>) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.service.ModelImageService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b76b438d.generateThumbnailImage(<generated>) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.service.ModelServiceImpl.persistModel(ModelServiceImpl.java:685) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.service.ModelServiceImpl.createModel(ModelServiceImpl.java:335) ~[flowable-ui-modeler-logic-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) [spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy424.createModel(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.flowable.ui.modeler.rest.app.ModelsResource.createModel(ModelsResource.java:131) [flowable-ui-modeler-rest-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.flowable.ui.common.filter.FlowableCookieFilter.doFilterInternal(FlowableCookieFilter.java:169) [flowable-ui-common-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

---

From testing it seems Docker
 - flowable/all-in-one:6.4.2 is Broken
 - flowable/all-in-one:6.4.2.1 looks fine (no crash)
 - Also 6.4.2.1 is not present in flowable GitHub (6.4.2 is present and it crashes with same error), so how do I checkout branch corresponding to docker-hub 6.4.2.1?

[image: dockerhub vs github]

Comment: issue report https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/issues/1911

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem in the base image that was used for the Flowable docker images (adoptopenjdk/openjdk8). A new version (6.4.2.1) was released that uses adoptopenjdk/openjdk11 as the base image

Comment: also flowable team has updated the issue ticket https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/issues/1911

Comment: Yes I know. I am also member of the team. I answered just in case someone stumbles on the same problem and doesn't follow the link to the issue